# lftp not removing remote files for me

Tags: linux

I'm trying to download some files from an ftp dump site (one of our clients) and then remove the files once downloaded (using linux).

After some digging around I've come up with lftp to do the task and have the following script successfully getting the files

```
lftp -u  uname,pwd -e "mirror --Remove-source-files --verbose Recordings /OSQA/recordings" 203.zzz.fff.xxx
```

When the download completes, I get a message saying

> 158 bytes transferred in 4 seconds (891b/s)
> To be removed: 0 directories, 4 files, 0 symlinks

but nothing is deleted.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  I need this to be in a script, so it's a pain not to be able to get rid of the source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be sure - do you have delete permissions on this ftp?

Comment: Thanks Redride, it seems it must have been a permissions problem.

I contacted the site owner to question this, they assured me that the permissions were OK, and yet, this morning when I test the script, it magically works.. lol.

Thanks for the assistance.

Peter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd got the same issue, in my case I have to add `--delete` to my cli :

```
lftp -u  uname,pwd -e "mirror --Remove-source-files --verbose --delete Recordings /OSQA/recordings" 203.zzz.fff.xxx
```