# lftp reverse mirror silently skips files in subfolders

Tags: mirroring, mirror, recursive

I'm using lftp to push content to an ftp-only web-server.  It worked to upload the files recursively at first, and even incrementally.

Any idea why this would skip files changed in a subfolder, but not skip files changed in the home directory?

**Details:**
I'm using the reverse mirror mode, which pushes local data up to the server instead of downloading it from the server.  Throughout the web, this is the recommended option for recursive upgrade.

Here's the full script (from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/106365/127281))

```
#!/bin/bash    
HOST="..."
USER="..."
PASS="..."
FTPURL="ftp://$USER:$PASS@$HOST"
LCD="/local/directory"
#RCD=""
#RCDCMD=cd $RCD;
#DELETE="--delete"
lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no;
set ftp:list-options -a;
open '$FTPURL';
lcd $LCD;
$RCDCMD \
mirror --reverse \
   $DELETE \
   --verbose \
   --exclude-glob .*swp \
   --exclude-glob .*swn \
   --exclude-glob .*swo"
```

The [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/120969/lftp-not-removing-remote-files-for-me), was solved by permission issues, which is not an issue in this case.  Everything is "rwxr-xr-x" on the server.

**Further Testing**:
The lftp seems to work intermittently.  For example, I will run the command twice, and it skips the changes, then the third time it works, correctly copying the changed files up to the server.

Comment: does `ls -R` work on the remote server?

Comment: I do not have SSH login on this server.  Are you referring to an ftp command?

Comment: Please do not downvote this question without providing feedback about what is wrong with it.  I believe the question is well-researched, and likely a common problem for those who must use lftp instead of rsync because, like me, they don't have ssh access to a website.

Comment: `ls -R` gets a mention in the lftp man page.  I presume it's an lftp command.

Comment: Yes, lftp's `ls -R` command works. On the other hand, files in recursive directories are also being correctly copied now too. Looks like I need to do some more testing on when the bug occurs and when it doesn't.

Comment: Now reported as bug: http://linux.overshoot.tv/ticket/5380. (This is a private page)

Answer (score 0):

Within the lftp command, run an `ls -R` before the `mirror`.

```
# Set variables as in the question
lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no;
set ftp:list-options -a;
open '$FTPURL';
lcd $LCD;
ls -R;   # This is the key line!
$RCDCMD \
mirror --reverse \
   $DELETE \
   --verbose \
   --exclude-glob .*swp \
   --exclude-glob .*swn \
   --exclude-glob .*swo"
```

I'm going to continue testing, but this has worked every time I've tested it so far...